# How to move line in SVG in one set direction

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, geometry

I have a rectangle that consists of 4 line shapes. I want to be able to resize it by dragging one of its 4 sides but it needs to maintain rectangle shape, I'll try to illustrate bellow:

[image]

Lines `ab`, `bc`, `cd`, `da` are individual line shapes. In this example, by dragging with mouse, I need to move line `cd` but it needs to maintain rectangle shape with other lines (also needs to work for all of the lines, `cd` is just example). So far I have a code for dragging the line:

```
function moveLine(previousCoo, x1, y1, x2, y2){ //following example above, x1 and y1 are point d and x2, y2 are point c
    if(document.getElementById('Line')){
        document.removeChild(document.getElementById('Line'));
    }
    var myLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "Line");
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x1);
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y1);
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x2);
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y2);
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "green");
    myLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", 3);
    $(myLine).mousemove(function (e) {  //on mouse move, mousedown is already determined from another function
        var coo = getCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY); //function for getting current mouse coordinates
        var dCoo = [coo[0] - previousCoo[0], coo[1] - previousCoo[1]];   //calculate how much the mouse was moved
        x1 += dCoo[0];
        y1 += dCoo[1];
        x2 += dCoo[0];
        y2 += dCoo[1];
        moveLine(coo, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }.bind(this));
    $(myLine).mouseup(function (e) {

        finish();

    }.bind(this));
    document.appendChild(myLine);
}
```

This works for only moving the line around but I need it to move only in the direction noted in the picture above. I tried playing with sinuses, cosinuses and what not but nothing worked. Can someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: This would be much easier if you used a transform to rotate the co-ordinate system. Then you could treat the lines/rect as being along an axis and just move their x (or y) locations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using  Robert Longson idea to rotate the coordinate system.

This is how I would do it:

The rect and the lines are drawn around the [0,0] point and the group they are in is rotated.
Also the lines have a class `h` for horizontal lines and `v` for vertical lines. Alternatively instead of clases you may check if x1 == x2 for vertical lines or y1 == y2 for horizontal lines.

When you drag the line you reset the value of `y1`, `y2` attributes for horizontal lines ant the `x1`, `x2` attributes for vertical lines.

The function `oMousePosSVG` is detecting the mouse position on the svg canvas.

```js
let lines = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#greenLines line"));
let dragging = false;
let theclass =  "";
let theLine = null;
let m = {}


lines.forEach((l,i) =>{
  l.addEventListener("mousedown",()=>{
    dragging = i+1;
    l.style.stroke = "red"
    theclass = l.getAttribute("class")
    theLine = lines[dragging - 1];
  })
})

  svg.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
    if(dragging){
       m = oMousePosSVG(e)
       if(theclass == "h"){
       theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"y1",m.y);
       theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"y2",m.y);
       }
       if(theclass == "v"){
       theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"x1",m.x);
       theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"x2",m.x);
       }
  }
  })

  svg.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>{
     lines[dragging - 1].style.stroke = "green"; 
     dragging = false;
  })


function oMousePosSVG(e) {
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = e.clientX;
      p.y = e.clientY;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
#greenLines line{stroke:green; stroke-width:5px;stroke-linecap:round}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" >
  <g transform="rotate(25)">
  <polygon id="poly" points="-50,-30 50,-30 50,30 -50,30 -50,30"/>
  <g id="greenLines">
    <line id="ab" class="h" x1="-50" y1="30"  x2="50" y2="30" />
    <line id="bc" class="v" x1="50" y1="30"  x2="50" y2="-30" />
    <line id="cd" class="h" x1="50" y1="-30" x2="-50" y2="-30"  />
    <line id="da" class="v" x1="-50" y1="-30"  x2="-50" y2="30"  /> 
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let you have base direction `B->C`, call it vector `BC`

```
BC = C - B = (C[0] - B[0], C[1] - B[1])
```

We can find projection (`P`) of your `coo` point onto `BC` direction. At first get vector

```
W = coo - B
```

then calculate projection using scalar product

```
BP = BC * (BC.dot.W) / (BC.dot.BC)
```

in coordinates:

```
t = (C[0] - B[0]) * (coo[0] - B[0]) + (C[1] - B[1]) * (coo[1] - B[1]) / 
        (C[0] - B[0]) * (C[0] - B[0]) + (C[1] - B[1]) * (B[1] - B[1])
BP[0] = B[0] + t * (C[0] - B[0])
BP[1] = B[1] + t * (C[1] - B[1])
```

Now it is easy to get new coordinates of point `C'` and `D'`

```
C' = B + BP
D' = A + BP
```

Comment: `D' = A + BP` where did you get `A`?

Comment: It is your vertex A - we need it to find new D position